# Can I stop the Gutmann method midway?

Tags: hard-drive, dban

Like the title says, I started running the Gutmann method (in dban) to wipe my HDD. When it started, it gave me about 12 hours remaining. It has slowed to a crawl now and shows 133 hours remaining after about 4 rounds. Are there negative implications to me just cycling power if I'm fine with the security that 4 passes provides?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. A single pass is sufficient, in general, and I've power cycled a system in the middle of a dban pass. Since data loss is a *desired outcome*, you shouldn't have any issues hitting the reset switch.

The guttman method is designed to use a variety of patterns and wiping method to securely erase *every* possible encoding method in use then. With modern drives having much smaller magnetic domains, a few scrubs with random data will do [according to guttman](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html#Epilogue).

With modern systems, the secure delete command will likely do a better job, faster.

Comment: You could also encrypt the entire volume with a program like TrueCrypt and a complex key, then just do a single sweep if you're paranoid.